# clone an option of dropdown and name it differently after storing it in the same dropdown

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, drop-down-menu

Can we clone an option of dropdown and name it differently after storing it in the same dropdown?

Like I selected an option from the dropdown (eg Apple) after cloning I need to store it as Apple_copy.

```
  <SELECT NAME="list" ID="list">
      <OPTION>Apple</OPTION>
  </SELECT>   

  <FORM NAME="myform" ACTION="" METHOD="GET">
      <INPUT TYPE="button" NAME="button" VALUE="Copy" onClick="CopyItem1()"/>
```

**JS**

```
    function CopyItem1() {
        $('#list1').append(function(){
            return $(this).find(':selected').clone(); //return the clone of selected option to be appended.
        });
    }
```

Comment: What you have tried till now?

Comment: @Learning I am able to add the clone in the same dropdown with the above code but need to save it with different naming so that it can be distinguished from the original.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I agree with parchambault, just remember that the OP needed to rename the option:

```
var $list = $('#list');             
var clone = $list.find('option:selected').clone();
var name = clone.html() + "_copy";
clone.attr("name", name);
clone.html(name);
$list.append(clone);
```

Answer (score 1):

You can only create a clone and append it to the select

```
function CopyItem1() {
    var $list = $('#list');
    var clone = $list.find('option:selected').clone();

    $list.append(clone);
}
```

voila!

Comment: I need to save the clone with different name. else It is cloning and adding in the same dropdown. I want to save the clone as Apple_copy or  anything else but it should be distinguished from the original one.

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
function CopyItem1()
   {
       var $list=$("#list");
      $list.append($list.find(':selected').clone().attr("name","newName").text("Apple_copy")); //return the clone of selected option to be appended.
   }
```

Here I am setting name to "newName" and text is changing to "Apple_copy"

You can check the fiddle [here](http://jsfiddle.net/gL4jf/2/)

**EDIT:**

After your comment

```
function CopyItem1()
   {
       var $list=$("#list");
       var $clone=$list.find(":selected").clone();
       var text=$clone.text(); 
       $list.append($clone.attr("name","newName").text(text +"_copy"));
   }
```

Now this will append "_copy" if you copy any selected item

Fiddle [here](http://jsfiddle.net/gL4jf/4/)

Comment: @LearningThere are many elements in the dropdown not only one. A user can select any element and want to make a copy of it